# Update a model within a model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
{
    "_id": "58fa4b4fa377ac2840cd1478",
    "password": "pass",
    "username": "test",
    "__v": 45,
    "stats": {
        "three": [
            {
                "_id": "58fceef81e862e16f0501c1c",
                "time": 115,
                "scramble": "L2 R' U' L2 F2 B R' U' B2 L F' B' D B' F' D U B",
                "status": 0,
                "date": "2017-04-23T18:14:16.412Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "58fceefd1e862e16f0501c1d",
                "time": 135,
                "scramble": "D F L2 U2 R2 B2 F2 R B D' R' F' B L U2 F' U2 F U' F",
                "status": 0,
                "date": "2017-04-23T18:14:21.434Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "58fcef031e862e16f0501c1e",
                "time": 101,
                "scramble": "R' F R B R' L2 B' U2 D R2 F L U R2 B2 D' F U R' D",
                "status": 0,
                "date": "2017-04-23T18:14:27.572Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "58fdc8311e862e16f0501c1f",
                "time": 87,
                "scramble": "L2 F B' F D' B2 L2 U B2 D U2 L B' F2 B2 F2 D' R",
                "status": 0,
                "date": "2017-04-24T09:41:05.334Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    "accountDate": "2017-04-21T18:11:27.946Z"
};
```

I have a model called "Users". This JSON is one of the user.
Ok so the objects in "three" are their own model called "Time". I want to select one of them by their id and then update it. How will I be able to do that? I am using mongoose. Obviously Time.findOne() doesnt work because the collection is of "Users" which **contain** "Time".

```
var timeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    time: Number,
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    scramble: String,
    status: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
});

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    accountDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    stats: {
        three: [timeSchema]
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you update your question using the [edit] link to show the mongoose schema definitions for both `User` and `Time` models?

Comment: @chridam Sure. Done

Comment: In that case use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) and the [**`$`** positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) in your update as `User.findOneAndUpdate({ "username": "test", "stats.three._id": "58fceef81e862e16f0501c1c" }, { "$set": { "stats.three.$.status": 1 } }, { "new": true }, callback);`

Comment: @chridam Doesnt work... :/

Comment: @chridam no wait it WORKED! Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

Code not compiled..

```
 yourUserModel.findById(userId, function(err,user) {  
          var i;
            if(err || user === null){
            return;
            }
           var stats = user.stats;

           for(i =0; i<stats.three.three.length; i=i+1) {
              if(stats.three[i]._id === yourId) { //id of object to be updated
                  stats.three[i].status = 1; //updating
    }

    }
user.stats = stats;
user.save();
            });
```